# Interaction between Telemechanics and a Glitter Boy Power Armor, what would happen?

Tags: combat, skills, rifts, palladium-system

A Mind Melter finds a functioning and unattended suit of Glitter Boy Power Armor. The Mind Melter decides to use Telemechanics on it in order to pilot it.

The Glitter Boy OCC states that non GB pilots can only operate the suit at a Basic level of proficiency while GB pilots default to the Elite proficiency. However, the Telemechanics power states that a Psionic can operate any machine at 80% scholastic skill expertise... but not which skill specifically, and all skills seem to be lumped under "scholastic" as per the general description in the Skills section.

The Mind Melter gets into a Hand to Hand fight while piloting the Glitter Boy and using the Telemechanics power.

Does the Mind Melter use the Basic as per the GB OCC description, the Elite skill somehow, the 80% "scholastic skill" as per the Telemechanics power (and if so, which skill does that translate as), or something else?

In short, what happens... and what level of proficiency does the Telemechanics power result in for the Mind Melter in Hand to Hand combat in the Glitter Boy?

Answer (score 1):

I'd stick with the Basic level. The Telemechanics power could, however, allow for +1 to Strike and Parry, help with maintenance and even secret modifications the original user has made.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).